# Adding Application Insights to Asp.Net Core 1.1.2

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-application-insights

I'm trying to add Application insights to my Asp.Net Core application. I followed the following instructions: [Getting Started with Application Insights for ASP.NET Core](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/wiki/Getting-Started-with-Application-Insights-for-ASP.NET-Core) (I'm working with VS2015 Update 3)

The issue I'm facing is this:

[image]

**project.json:**

[image]

Build Options:

[image]

Many thanks in advance!

**[Update]**

By making use of the JS snippet provided on the Azure Application Insights page, I was able to add some insights to the web site. But I've noticed that the script doesn't pick up the routing of angular. So page changes aren't listed. Only a reload causes an event to fire. Not sure if the same would happen in my initial approach

**[Update 2]**

I ended up making use of the following library: [angular-appinsights](https://github.com/johnhidey/angular-appinsights) - which inadvertently **solved** my issue

Comment: Did you restore the dependencies? I.e. `dotnet restore`?

Comment: Soz, forgot to mention that in my question. Yes. I ran it a couple of times.